# Solve an initial value problems ODE with a time-dependent parameter

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I was trying to compute an ODE of attitude kinematics eqs in Python using the solve_ivp function, but the problem is that one of the parameters, the angular velocity omega, changes, and I would like to take this into account. I have previously computed omega from another ODE, and now I would like to use the result I got as input for this other ODE.

This is what I did:

```
def fun2(time, euler):
    omegax = 5.2928e-10; omegay = -2.5347e-11; omegaz = 2.6609e-6
    dot1 = (omegax*np.sin(euler[2]) + omegay*np.cos(euler[2]))/np.sin(euler[1])
    dot2 = omegax*np.cos(euler[2]) - omegay*np.sin(euler[2])
    dot3 = omegaz - (omegax*np.sin(euler[2]) + omegay*np.cos(euler[2]))/np.tan(euler[1])

    return np.array([dot1, dot2, dot3])

angles = integrate.solve_ivp(fun2, tspan, euler0, t_eval = t, method = 'RK45', dense_output = True, rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22)
```

Here I used a constant omega to run the code, but I would like it to change. The omega I have obtained in the other ODE (always using solve_ivp) is in the form of a matrix, where there are all the omegax, y and z in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd column respectively, with 1000000 rows.
One thing I tried was to solve the previous ODE inside fun2, like this:

```
def fun2(time, euler):
    x_t = integrate.solve_ivp(fun, tspan, omega0, t_eval=t, method='RK45', dense_output=True, rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22)
    omegax = x_t.y[0];   omegay = x_t.y[1];   omegaz = x_t.y[2]
    dot1 = (omegax*np.sin(euler[2]) + omegay*np.cos(euler[2]))/np.sin(euler[1])
    dot2 = omegax*np.cos(euler[2]) - omegay*np.sin(euler[2])
    dot3 = omegaz - (omegax*np.sin(euler[2]) + omegay*np.cos(euler[2]))/np.tan(euler[1])

    return np.array([dot1, dot2, dot3])

angles = integrate.solve_ivp(fun2, tspan, euler0, t_eval = t, method = 'RK45', dense_output = True, rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22)
```

> Unfortunately it did not work, and I got this error message: "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,1000000) (3,)" and now I'm stuck. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: full error message please

Comment: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,1000000) (3,)" Do you also want the traceback?

Comment: traceback?  Why would i want that?  All it tells us is WHERE the error occurs, and what variables are involved.  I have better things to do than guess those details.

Comment: @MrRobot please also edit your question by including both the error message and the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve the coupled system as coupled system

```
def fun2(t, euleromega):
    euler, omega = euleromega[:3], euleromega[3:]
    dotomega = fun(t,omega)

...
    return np.concatenate([[dot1,dot2,dot3], dotomega])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I did it but I'm getting a weird result when I solve the ODE. I solve it using "x_t = integrate.solve_ivp(fun2, tspan, euleromega0, t_eval = t, method = 'RK45', dense_output = True, rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22)", but when I call one of the solutions (e.g. y1 = x_t.y[0]) I only get one single value, instead I should get an array of the same length of the time array

Comment: `t_eval` and `dense_output` exclude each other, if you know where  you want the samples use `t_eval`, if you need random access to the solution use the more memory-expensive `dense_output`, and if you know what you are searching for use the event mechanism, probably in the non-terminal version. // Anyway, your relative tolerance is way too small, the floating point format `float` or `float64` usually only allows relative tolerances down to `1e-13`, sometimes `1e-14`. Check `x_t.success` and  `x_t.message` for error messages.

Comment: I checked x_t.success and x_t.message and I got "False", and "Required step size is less than spacing between numbers", even after putting dense_output to False. I googled the error message and found out it may happen because of a singularity, or the tolerance too small, like you said. Nevertheless, I tried reducing the time evaluations and increase the tolerances (up to 1e-4), but the error message persists.

Comment: What are the typical numerical scales of your components, what would you expect them to be from physical considerations? // If there are no other considerations, you should set about `atol = scale*rtol`, so that in the settings as posted you would have the scale of the components at `1e-9`. That guideline is only valid if all components have about the same scale. Otherwise set the scale and thus `atol` per component, the solver supports arrays for the tolerances.

Comment: Yes there is an important difference in scale, maybe that's the problem, or part of it. In fact the 3 components of omega are in the range of 1e-6 ÷ 1e-10, while the angles are in the order of +-pi.

Comment: Yes, that is significant enough. You get similar scale differences in inner solar system simulations if the time unit is the second and the distance unit is meter or km. There changing units to day(or week) and AU works better, with less difference between the scales of distance and velocity. So set, as example, ´rtol=tol` and `atol=np.array([1,1,1,1e-7,1e-7,1e-7])*tol`

Comment: I had the derivative wrong, the order in the derivative has to be the same as in the input.